# How can I move the bolded "Amethyst" to the left?

Tags: html, css

How can I move the Amethyst in bold to the left of the page? I tried using float: left but it didn't work. Here is my code. Thanks for the help!

```css
body {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.navclass {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.amethyst-paragraph {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}

.amethyst {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Crystal Healing</h1>

<strong>Amethyst</strong>
<p class="amethyst-paragraph">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa.</p>
<img src="http://hibiscusmooncrystalacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/amethyst-cluster.jpg" class="amethyst">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make it a paragraph. Float is not required.

```css
body {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.navclass {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.amethyst-paragraph {
  width: 400px;
}

.amethyst {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Crystal Healing</h1>
<p><strong>Amethyst</strong></p>
<p class="amethyst-paragraph">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa.</p>
<img src="http://hibiscusmooncrystalacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/amethyst-cluster.jpg" class="amethyst">
```

Comment: Actually I have another question. I turned the bolded Amethyst into a paragraph. I kept the float: left in Amethyst-Paragraph so that the image stays to the right of the text. Now how do I get rid of the extra space between the Amethyst in bold and the paragraph? Thanks

Comment: @DragonG You can change the bottom margin for the paragraph containing the bold text.

Comment: Ok I have another question. When I try to make a new paragraph below my first paragraph, it ends up to the right of the paragraph. How do I place my new paragraph below the first paragraph?